# How to - Symfony 2 Perform CRUD without passing ID to url

Tags: php, symfony

After long time of lerking on these boards I have finally decided to make my first post. I have recently started to play around with Symfony (2.4, don't yell at me please :) ). Using doctrine's terminal commands I generated CRUD events. Now, that is great and all, except that you have to pass the ID in the url, for example: www.mydomain.com/account/16/. This will pre-fill the form with the data from a row that has id 16 in mysql. My question is, how do I manipulate the pre-made CRUD (only interested in the update) so that I don't have to pass the id to the url, but rather, it renders the form based on the id the logged in user has associated with their account?

Here is my code:

```
class AccountController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing Event entity.
 * @Route("/account/{id}", name="post_login_account_edit")
 * @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated()")
 */
public function editAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Event entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);

    return $this->render('UserBundle:Account:account.html.twig', array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView()
    ));
}

/**
 * Creates a form to edit a Event entity.
 *
 * @param User $entity The entity
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createEditForm(User $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('post_login_account_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
        'method' => 'PUT',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

    return $form;
}
/**
 * Edits an existing User entity.
 * @Route("/account/{id}/update", name="post_login_account_update")
 * @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated()")
 */
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Event entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('post_login_account'));
    }

    return $this->render('UserBundle:Account:account.html.twig', array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView()
    ));
}
```

}

Comment: Change route address to something else (without the id param) `* @Route("/account"`. Remove the $id from the function declaration as you will no longer be getting it from the route `public function editAction()`. Change the line `$entity = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->find($id);` to `$entity = $this->getUser();` to fetch the currently logged in user instead of some user by id

Comment: THAT WORKED!!! THANK YOU!

Comment: Hope it made at least some sense as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply get logged in user in controller:

```
$entity = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting so quickly. I made the changes you recommended, and I am getting a blank page with nothing in the body. The debugger shows no errors.